# What are the ways to delete objects in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

In unmanaged C++, how do I clear objects from memory?

Comment: It depends on how you create them.

Comment: If you don't explicitly use new or malloc (or some crazy strdup :), you don't have to. It just works!

Comment: BTW, it is not "unmanaged C++", it is native C++.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That depends how you allocated them:

- `new` should be matched by `delete`
- `new[]` should be matched by `delete[]`
- `malloc` should be matched by `free` (you should never have to use this in C++ though)

Now, forget all these things, use [Smart Pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) and read about [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Comment: Using `malloc` in C++ (consider user defined types) is a bad idea.

Comment: @Prasoon: Way ahead of you :)

Comment: WITH NULL: error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 940

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: If you have a specific problem with specific code, post that code (a **minimal** compilable example that reproduces the error). Do *not* post that code in a comment. Edit your question, or ask a new question about it.

Comment: That C2679 error suggests that you tried to assign null to an object which is not a pointer. This only works with "numberlike" primitive types, and pointers, and with objects that have an explicit operator= for an int type. Note that in any case assigning null to a pointer __does not__ free any memory.

Comment: @Prasoon: no I would just say it is for advanced use only, when you intend to use it with placement-new. In general use you probably don't want to be doing that, but if implementing a memory/object pool you may well want to.

Answer (score 1):

You need not worry about variables allocated on stack. If memory is allocated on the heap using `new` you need to use `delete`

```
MyClass *p = new MyClass(); 
// Code

delete p;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete those which you allocate with new, otherwise an exception will be thrown.

Comment: delete Object; delete [] Array;

Comment: You almost certainly won't get an exception; it's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    Object obj = Object;
    // no need to delete this one it will be delete when it gos out of scop
}

Object* obj;
{
    obj = new Object();
    // you need to delete this one because you used the "new" keyword, even if it gos out of scop
}
delete obj;
```